# How to make json file a list in Python

Tags: python, json

as said, I'd like to open a json file and make it into a list, in order to append new elements to it and then dump all back into the json file.

Here is my code(the commented part is what I previously tried):

```
class Carta:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__lista = []
        # try:
        #    f = open(self.__filename,"r")
        # except:
        #     f = open(self.__filename, "w")
        #     f.close()
        #     f = open(self.__filename, "r")

        with open(self.__filename) as file:
            self.__lista = json.load(file)

        # read=json.load(f)
        # for c in leggi:
        #     self.__lista.append(c)
        # print(self.__lista)
        # f.close()

    def add(self, c):
        self.__lista.append(c)

    def save(self):
        f = open(self.__filename, "w")
        for c in self.__lista:
            f.write("%s\n" % str(c))
        f.close()
```

Comment: Can you share what the data looks like? Generally JSON is used for dictionary-like structures, not simple lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't work if you read from a JSON file, json list and then write custom string. Because next time you read the JSON file it's gonna fail.

So, during write/save you should make it json itself. Here's the code the explains how to do it.

```
import json


class Carta:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__lista = list()
        self.read_from_json_file()

    def read_from_json_file(self):
        with open(self.__filename) as file:
            self.__lista = json.load(file)

    def write_to_json_file(self):
        with open(self.__filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.__lista, f)

    def add(self, value):
        self.__lista.append(value)
```

The reason you should use `with open(filename, mode) as f:` instead of `f = open(filename)` is because at the end of with block the file is automatically closed. Otherwise you've to call `f.close()` every time you open a file.

`json.load` - reads json data from file, converts to python data type/structure.

`json.dump` - read python data type/structure, converts it into string and stores it in the file (file handle) and saves the file.

Using pdb to trace errors

```
import json
import pdb


class Carta:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.__filename = filename
        self.__lista = list()
        self.read_from_json_file()

    def read_from_json_file(self):
        pdb.set_trace()  # to pause execution and start debugger

        # When paused,
        # type n to continue to next line,
        # type c to continue execution or to continue to the next loop
        # type b <file_name>:<line_number> to add another break point, where <file_name> and <line_number> are place holders
        # Example, b /home/username/hello.py:43, will add breakpoint at 43 line of hello.py in /home/username path
        # type q to quit debugger and halt execution 
        with open(self.__filename) as file:
            self.__lista = json.load(file)

    def write_to_json_file(self):
        with open(self.__filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.__lista, f)

    def add(self, value):
        # Second breakpoint
        pdb.set_trace()
        self.__lista.append(value)
```

Or just run your file with

`python -m pdb file.py` and then add breakpoints. It will pause in the first line itself and return you a (pdb) console where you can add breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you very for your precious help. I'm kind of new to this site, is there a way I can show you better all the errors I keep getting?

Comment: @MohammedSahib Are they related to this particular question?

Comment: @AMC actually they are. When calling write_to_json_file I get the following error: bject is not JSON serializable

Comment: @MohammedSahib Can you add the entirety of your code to the OP? Or make a new question with it, I don’t know.

Comment: @MohammedSahib I would recommend to use pdb instead of asking questions in stackoverflow or elsewhere for debugging python errors. I will make an edit in my answer to show how to use it

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json

#read from file
with open("demofile.txt", "r") as f: x = f.read()

#parse
y = json.loads(x)

#edit
y["user"] = { "fname": "John", "lname": "Who"}

#save to file
with open("demofile.txt", "w") as f: f.write(json.dumps(y))
```

https://repl.it/@KrzysztofPecyna/PythonJsonExample

Answer (score 0):

To read `JSON` from a file:

```
import json

with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

To add new data:

```
data['key'] = "value"
```

To write `JSON` to a file:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: so i would have to append a new element to "data"?

Comment: JSON is a structured format, so you can't simply add stuff to the end of the file, like you would with a plain text file. A list is demarcated by an end marker `]` so at a minimum you'd have to rewrite the end to remove the old end marker, write your new data, and write a new end marker. But in practice we tend to just write to a new file and remove the old if it's not extremely large (at which point maybe switch to a proper database instead of a sequential file).